# Expand last table column to fill container

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you expand the last column of a table to fill the parent container without specifying a width for the container?
In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh49dzcs/1/), I want the last column of the green table to fill the blue container. The width of the container should only be determined by its text.

```
.container{
  background-color: #003388;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

table {
  background-color: #008833;
  color: white;
  width:auto;
}

table tr td:last-child {
  /* width:100%; */
}
```

Setting the width of the last td fills the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is given below. It uses...

- `width: 100%` rule (instead of `width: auto`) to make table fill the container
- `width: 1px; white-space: nowrap;` combo trick to make all the columns define their width based on content width; without that rule it seems there's no simple way to override default behaviour of `table-layout: auto` sharing the whole width between columns equally.
- `max-width: 1px` for the last column to ensure that `inline-block` container is not extended when that column grows, and text is wrapped instead

```css
.container{
    background-color: #003388;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
}

table {
    background-color: #008833;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

table td:not(:last-child) {
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

table td:last-child {
   max-width: 1px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
long text long text long text long text long text long text

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Cardinality</th>
        <th>Price per item</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>$2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pear</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>$3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sausage</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>$0.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pineapple</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tomato</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>$1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lightsaber</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$99 999 999999999 99999999 99999999</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! One follow up question: The parent container now grows when the contents in the last column are sufficiently long. How would you go about limiting the width of the last column to avoid this and instead hide the overflow / wrap the text instead?

Comment: You mean something like this: `table td:last-child { max-width: 1px; }`?

Comment: Perfect! This is very unintuitive...

Comment: It is indeed. :) Updated the answer (made a couple of flops while doing this, though).

Answer (score 0):

Use fractional units fr to automatically take up the fraction you desire